# Making multiple http calls inside foreach loop async

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, async-await, observable, es6-promise

Lets say I have a foreach loop

```
  Object.keys(this.treeMap).forEach(id=>{
    this.getSelectionById(id);
  })
  this.processAfterHttpCalls();
```

and getSelectionById method makes an http call

```
  getSelectionById(id){
      let requestBody = {
        id: id
      };
      this.subscription = this.dependenciesService.getInstancesByCSIId(requestBody)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.someProcessing(data);
        }, err => {
          this.appMessageService.showMessage(this.appMessageService.ERROR, err);
        })
    }
```

But is there a way i can make those call async so once call the http calls inside the forEach block have been finished, I can call another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your getSelectionById returns an observable :

```
getSelectionById(id){
    let requestBody = {
        id: id
    };
    return this.dependenciesService.getInstancesByCSIId(requestBody)
        .pipe(map(data => this.someProcessing(data));
}
```

You can zip all http calls inside an single observable :

```
zip(...Object.keys(this.treeMap).map(id=> this.getSelectionById(id)))
    .subscribe(_ => this.processAfterHttpCalls(), err => this.appMessageService.showMessage(this.appMessageService.ERROR, err));
```

This way all http calls are made in parallel, and the processAfterHttpCalls is called when all http calls have finished.

Comment: well getInstancesByCSIId doesn't return an observable

Comment: Since you called subscribe on the result of getInstancesByCSIId in your method getSelectionById I thought it returned an Observable

Comment: even after changing, its giving error  __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6_rxjs_operators__.b.apply(...).subscribe is not a function

Comment: do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: I updated my answer because there was a mistake in the error handling. Instead of using the catchError operator, I moved the error handling to the subscribe method.

Comment: actually problem im having is the this.someProcessing(data) is not being called, it doesn't come inside the map operator

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your arrow function as a async function.

Example:

```
Object.keys(this.treeMap).forEach(async id=>{
    await this.getSelectionById(id);
})
```

Comment: even if it does make those calls async, where should i put   this.processAfterHttpCalls();

Comment: if you need to do this statement after each request you can put in the foreach statement, but if you want to do after all requests you dont need to change your code.

Answer (score -2):

I think you could use setTimeout, since it run asynchronous:

```
Object.keys(this.treeMap).forEach(id=>{
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        self.getSelectionById(id);
    },10);
})
```